# Fractional part of integers within a specific interval

Tags: mathematics, logical-deduction

Three positive integers $a,b,c$ have the property that $b > 2a$ and $c > 2b$.
Is it always possible to find a real number $r$, such that each fractional part of the numbers $r\cdot a$, $r\cdot b$ and $r\cdot c$ lies within
the interval $(\frac{1}{3}, \frac{2}{3}]$ ?

Comment: This might be an acceptable question on this site, but why not posting it on a more suitable site, such as the mathematics site?

Comment: @WhatsUp, right, it is sometimes hard to decide which site fits best for such questions. I keep it here and see, if somebody wants to give it a try.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Yes, it is possible.

Proof:

> Let us think of *r* as a time, the fractional parts of the other variables can then be understood as a circular track of unit length on which *a*,*b*,*c* travel each at their own, constant speed. Two thirds of the track are "neutral" and one third is the target.

> Because *b* travels at more than twice the speed of *a* it will move more than double the distance in the same time. In particular, while *a* traverses the target, *b* will cover more ground than fits in the neutral zone. In other words *b* will for some of the time be in the target, too.

> We can make the same argument w.r.t. *b* and *c*, but that does not directly imply that all three will be in the target at the same time. To demonstrate this it will suffice to show that (*) during some of *b*'s cycles *a* will be in the target for the entire time *b* is. There are two cases:

> Case 1) *b* is a multiple of *a*: if *b*/*a*>=4 (*) is clearly satisfied because one passage of *a* through the target translates to at least 4/3 cycles for *b* which are guaranteed to contain at least one contigouous sweep through the target. But if *b*/*a*=3 then we can directly verify that *a*'s very first passage trough the target fully contains one of *b*'s.

> Case 2) *b* is not a multiple of *a*. Then because their ratio is rational, we will encounter a finite set of phase shifts (i.e. offsets of *b*'s cycles relative to the beginnings of each of *a*'s cycles) which will be of the form 1/*n* 2/*n* 3/*n* etc. Each offset of *b* contains a shifted period of length >2/3 (at *a* units) when *b* is in the target zone. *a*'s target of width 1/3 will be fully inside for a stretch of offsets of width >1/3. If *n*>=3 these must cover the entire loop. If *n*=2 the ratio *b*/*a* must be 5/2 or more. Now each offset of *b* contains a target zone of length >=5/6. Therefore a stretch of length >=1/2 of offsets will contain the entire *a* target. As *n*=2 this is just enough to cover the full loop.

Comment: Is there any way to make Case 2 more rigorous? I can see in my mind's eye how the phase shift for b/a >2 will guarantee (\*) but I always like to be able to back these things up with an algebraic argument. +1 from me for the formulation of (\*)

Comment: @hexomino I was a bit sloppy with that part of the argument, hope it is better now.

Comment: Nice solution using speed travel.